# No adapter attached; skipping layout onCreateView()

Tags: java, android, adapter, android-recyclerview

Trying to implement RecyclerView into my application, I don't understand why i'm getting "No adapter attached; skipping layout" I thought i clearly set it up in the onCreateView. Some other posts suggested to move it to Oncreate() but when i do that i get many more errors. I followed this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OoCySqneJno) if it helps. Here is my Main Activity class

I do not believe this is a duplicate of another question, although it might be similar. when moved to onCreate() the entire application crashes.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity  {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private Adapter adapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState){
    View layout=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
    recyclerView= (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.meme_list);
    adapter = new Adapter(this,getData());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return layout;

}

public static List<Memes> getData(){
    List<Memes> data = new ArrayList<>();
    String[] names ={"meme1", "meme2", "meme3"};
    for(int i=0; i<names.length; i++)
    {
        Memes meme = new Memes();
        meme.name=names[i];
        data.add(meme);

    }
    return data;
}
```

Here is the Adapter Class

```
public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.MyViewHolder> {

private LayoutInflater inflater;
List<Memes> data = Collections.emptyList();
public Adapter(Context context, List<Memes> data){
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data=data;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.meme_item, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Memes current=data.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(current.name);


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    TextView title;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        title=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);

    }
}
```

main activity xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/tool_bar">

</include>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:id="@+id/meme_list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

XML for layout of recycler view items

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Dummy text"/>
```

(Yes, the app consists of memes, previous version pulled in a lot of users though)

Comment: post your activity_main and xml file

Comment: You return null on the onCreateViewHolder method, return holder.

Comment: added the XML files, ill try returning holder

Comment: I set onCreateViewHolder to return holder, a couple logcat prompts went away but it still maintains No adapter attached

Comment: @IceMAN it's not duplicate. He just has newbie mistakes totally different from that upvoted question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try move the code in `onCreateView()` method of your Activity to `onCreate()`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.meme_list);
    adapter = new Adapter(this,getData());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

You also need to return `ViewHolder` as @Yasin Kaçmaz 's answer.

Comment: @Rey Pham Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this. I looked my working recycler view code and found this difference:

```
@Override

public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) 

{View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.meme_item, parent, false);
MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
return view;}
```

**return view on here instead of return null**

Comment: You have to return `MyViewHolder` object, not `View`.